# How JSessionId is exchanged beween the client and server using Hiddenform fields?

Tags: java, cookies, session

Can anybody explain the following:

> The unique JSESSIONID generated by the
>   server for every client is exchanged
>   between the client and server using
>   **Hidden form field**

Thanks

Comment: That looks like a quote; can you link to where it comes from? I've never heard of jsessionid in hidden form fields; only URL-rewriting (which screws up SEO) and cookies.

Comment: a quote from a badly-written homework assignment, mayhap....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What server technology is this? Technically, you could do some form of session tracking if a form was posted every request, but I've never seen someone attempt this. It isn't something in any Java EE API I've come across.

The [Servlet specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) only lists three session tracking mechanisms: HTTP cookies; SSL sessions; and URL rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** true. It's been exchanged as a cookie.

Cookies are specified in the HTTP request and response headers. To see it yourself, use some tool with which you can view those headers, such as for example [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Firefox Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/).

Maybe you confused it with the "view state" which some MVC frameworks indeed passes as a hidden input field.